# JavaScript While Loop Array Undefined output

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

```js
var v = 0
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var beasts = [{
  "kind": [{
    "q": "a"
  }, {
    "q": "b"
  }, {
    "q": "c"
  }]
}];
while (x.indexOf(beasts[0].kind[v].q)) {
  v++
  console.log("loop")
}
```

undefined output, whats wrong?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: You are doing it way more complicated than you need to. There is [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) if you want to find the index, and I see that you have tagged it with sort, so you might be interested in [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `v == 0`, the test is `x.indexOf("a")`. This returns `0`, which is falsey, so the loop ends immediately.

The proper way to use `indexOf()` is `x.indexOf(...) != -1`.

You also need to check that `v` is within the size of `beasts[0].kind`, otherwise you'll get an error when you reach the end of the array.

```js
var v = 0
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var beasts = [{
  "kind": [{
    "q": "a"
  }, {
    "q": "b"
  }, {
    "q": "c"
  }]
}];

while (v < beasts[0].kind.length && x.indexOf(beasts[0].kind[v].q) != -1) {
  v++
  console.log("loop")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the snippet that your condition in `while` evaluates to `0` which is a falsy value. `While` loop never runs!

```js
var v = 0
var x = ["a","b","c"];
var beasts = [{"kind": [{"q": "a"}, {"q": "b"}, {"q": "c"}]}];
while (x.indexOf(beasts[0].kind[v].q)) {
v++
console.log("loop")
}
console.log(beasts[0].kind[v].q);
console.log(x.indexOf(beasts[0].kind[v].q));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to check the `undefined` case for `beasts[0].kind[v]` since, you are incrementing the value of `v` inside `while` loop the last value of `v` will be more than the length of inner array which will result in `undefined`. You also do not need `indexOf` computation.

```js
var v = 0
var x = ["a","b","c"];
var beasts = [{"kind": [{"q": "a"}, {"q": "b"}, {"q": "c"}]}];
while (beasts[0].kind[v]) {
  v++;
  console.log("loop");
}
```

But if you want to ensure the property `q` you can use this

```js
var v = 0
var x = ["a","b","c"];
var beasts = [{"kind": [{"q": "a"}, {"q": "b"}, {"q": "c"}]}];
while (beasts[0].kind[v] && x.indexOf(beasts[0].kind[v].q) != -1) {
  v++;
  console.log("loop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the object exist.

```js
var v = 0
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var beasts = [{
  "kind": [{
    "q": "a"
  }, {
    "q": "b"
  }, {
    "q": "c"
  }]
}];
while (beasts[0].kind[v]) {
  console.log(x.indexOf(beasts[0].kind[v].q))
  v++
}
```